# Query created from Query returned from cfspreadsheet not having proper values

Tags: coldfusion, cfspreadsheet

Today I came across a very odd case while reading a vlue from a spreadsheet and trying to filter them on a condition and a create a spreadsheet from the filtered data. Here are my steps

1. Read Excel sheet

   ```
   <cfspreadsheet action="read" src="#local.sFilePath#"    excludeHeaderRow="true" headerrow ="1" query="local.qExcelData" sheet="1" />
   ```
2. Create a holding Query

   ```
   <cfset local.columnNames = "LoanNumber,Product," />
   <cfset local.qSuccessData = queryNew(local.columnNames,"VarChar,VarChar") />
   ```
3. Filter the Excel returned query on a condition and add the valid ones into the new Holding query

   ```
   <cfloop query="local.qExcelData" >
           <cfif ListFind(local.nExceptionRowList,local.qExcelData.currentrow) EQ 0>
             <cfset queryAddRow(local.qSuccessData) />
             <cfset querySetCell(local.qSuccessData, 'LoanNumber', local.qExcelData['Loan Number']) />
             <cfset querySetCell(local.qSuccessData, 'Product', local.qExcelData['Product']) />
           </cfif>
   </cfloop>
   ```
4. Create the new spreadsheet

   ```
   <cfspreadsheet action="write" query="local.qSuccessData" filename="#local.sTempSuccessFile#" overwrite="true">
   ```

However I am getting the following content in my excel sheet

```
Loannumber                           Product
coldfusion.sql.column@87875656we    coldfusion.sql.column@89989ER
```

Please help on this to get it work.

Comment: FWIW, `coldfusion.sql.column@87875656we` is the string representation of a complex object (like a whole query column, rather than one of the individual values within that column).  The first part is the object's class name: `coldfusion.sql.column` and the second is the object's [hashcode value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_hashCode%28%29).

Comment: @Leigh, Thanks for your clarification.

Comment: @Leigh, that was an informative que

Comment: @shemy - You are welcome and +1 for a "well written" question :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the query loop is not mapping values to the Holding-Query properly.

Please modify your loop as below:

```
<cfloop query="local.qExcelData" >
    <cfif ListFind(local.nExceptionRowList,local.qExcelData.currentrow) EQ 0>
      <cfset queryAddRow(local.qSuccessData) />
      <cfset querySetCell(local.qSuccessData, 'LoanNumber', local.qExcelData['Loan Number'][currentRow]) />
      <cfset querySetCell(local.qSuccessData, 'Product', local.qExcelData['Product'][currentRow]) />
    </cfif>
</cfloop>
```

Comment: tried your code..[currentRow] has saved my time. Thanks @Yoosaf Abdulla.